# Storyboard Set Width / Height for Custom View in Autolayout Similar to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

Labels are really convenient in iOS `autolayout` because they don't require a `constraints` to determine size, they only require an X and a Y position. For static text this is great.

I have a custom view that I would like to provide a default size to auto layout similar to `UILabels`. Is this possible? I am familiar with `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable`, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I am using `autolayout` in `storyboards`, but I imagine the solution would work for `storyboards` + programmatic.

I know I can just set the `height` and `width`, but this is view that will be used everywhere so it would be nice to have the `width` / `height` dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no smooth way to add `UIView` without specifying its size values, i.e. its `width` and `height`.

Speaking of auto-layout, there are 2 options you got, probably you are already aware of too. 1) you should either set `UIView's` size values, or 2. you set other UI Objects' sizes so that auto-layout can understand the size of `UIView`.

Speaking of programmatically, upon creating `UIView` object, if you do not provide frame, then it is not shown. Although this might be a solution to put at any point with any size, it might be not ideal when you are using xibs or storyboards, since there would be a gap on those interfaces which may also confuse development.

The way I am thinking of includes using both `intrinsicContentSize` and `IBDesignable`. I made a little demo for this purpose and you can find this code below. I will share 2 examples, one is inherited from `UILabel` and the other is inherited from `UIView`, so that I can show usage of `intrinsicContentSize` easier.

Below is the `UIView` one.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UIDemoView: UIView {

    func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 5
        clipsToBounds = true
    }    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setup()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let newWidth = 100
        let newHeight = 100
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

And below is the UILabel one.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UIDemoLabel: UILabel {

    func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        clipsToBounds = true
        textAlignment = .center
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setup()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let superSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let newWidth = superSize.width + superSize.height
        let newHeight = superSize.height
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

Here is the output on auto-layout

[image: Output]

I intentionally showed the constraints on both object, so you can check if I understand you correctly. They both have only 2 constraints: top and center alignment.

`UILabels` have theirs own `intrinsicContentSize`, so when overriding them we might use their already given `intrinsicContentSize` as a reference, as a guidance to whatever we want to do. `UIViews` `intrinsicContentSize` is not set, therefore we must find a way to give them specific sizes. With not being sure, I am guessing for `UILabel` `intrinsicContentSize` implementation, logic is most probably related with the size of the text. You can simply pass constants like above code, or you can use any custom logic to provide `CGFloats`.

Just a thought of mine: Even though I came with this solution, I am not fan of `IBDesignables`. From my perspective, they slow down the development because of its buggy nature. Thus, to be fully honest, I'd rather 1. putting `UIView` objects on xibs and `storyboards`, 2. changing its class from `UIView` to custom `UIView` class, 3. settings its constraints, 4. setting remaining properties programmatically from its `IBOutlet`. This is more of a traditional way, tho :)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Yes I agree IBDesignables aren't worth any potential benefit due to their slowness.

Answer (score 0):

You can override

```
var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { get }
```

property of UIView and calculate and return the height and width of the view based on its contents.

Ref : [intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. But when I set this property on my view Xcode still throws an error in the storyboard that the view needs a hight and width. I tried making the class @IBDesignable, but no luck